# Delphi: How to use TShiftState type variable?

Tags: delphi, keypress

I am developing a Delphi application.
On TImage.MouseDown event I want to do `X` task if shift key is pressed, `Y` task if control key is pressed and `Z` task if any of them is not pressed. For that I am using `TShiftState` variable. Now I have a function in which I have to pass this variable as parameter.

```
procedure Something(keyState : TShiftState);
```

Now In this function what I should right to check the state of key?

```
if KeyState <> ssShift then begin

end;
```

The above code shows error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIUC you want the empty set `[]`:

```
Something([ssShift]); // X
Something([ssCtrl]); // Y
Something([]); // Z
```

Regarding your update:

```
procedure Something(keyState : TShiftState);
begin
  if ssShift in KeyState then // KeyState contains ssShift (and maybe more)
    X;
  if ssCtrl in KeyState then // KeyState contains ssCtrl (and maybe more)
    Y;
  if [ssShift, ssCtrl] * KeyState = [] then // KeyState contains neither ssShift nor ssCtrl
    Z;
end;
```

If you are only interested in ssShift and ssCtrl, and the other values (ssAlt, ssLeft, ...) don't matter, you can mask the latter ones out:

```
procedure Something(keyState : TShiftState);
var
  MaskedKeyState : TShiftState
begin
  MaskedKeyState := KeyState * [ssShift, ssCtrl];
  if ssShift in MaskedKeyState then // MaskedKeyState contains ssShift
    X;
  if ssCtrl in MaskedKeyState then // MaskedKeyState contains ssCtrl
    Y;
  if MaskedKeyState = [] then // MaskedKeyState contains neither ssShift nor ssCtrl
    Z;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks... You provide all I need.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ssShift in keyState then
  ShowMessage('1')
else if ssCtrl in keyState then
  ShowMessage('2')
else
  ShowMessage('3')
```

try this